# Implementation of PID controller in PIC microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, embedded, control-system

I want to to implement a PID controller for motor speed control, so I have gone through an [application note published by Microchip](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes/an964).

On page 6/14, equation 8 and 9, a description of a PID equation is given with a following statements:

- Calculate derivative term using (Td/Ts)[E(n) - E(n-1)], where Td is Kd/Kp.
- Actual equation used is Kd(en0-en3)/(Kp·X·3·Ts), where X is an unknown scaling factor
- Kp·X·3·Ts  precalculated to be 32 to increase the speed the PID loop.

Could anyone explaine to me the X factor, that I think has to do with the hardware limitations of the PIC? How to choose that factor ?
How is Kp·X·3·Ts  precalculated to be 32, when the PID is not yet tuned?

Answer (score 4):

The actual algorithm is using integer math in C. The ideal 'unknown' factor X varies with the Kd to keep some significant bits in the answer without overflowing. In this case Kd is an integer bounded by the ADC bits.

As the app note says:

> (Similar scaling factors are also used when calculating the integral
> and proportional terms).

In this case, -120 < (en0-en3) < 120

The code may or may not be correct- looks to me like

`derivative_term = derivative_term * kd;`

.. can easily overflow if the Kd pot is turned up all the way (assuming 16-bit ints) but that's outside the scope of the question and this answer (and it's not clear which compiler is being used and how non-standard it might be).

Rather than actually dividing by the constant 32, a >> 5 shift is used, which is fast on the primitive 8-bit PIC MCU. The compensating factor of 32 would appear if the Kd pot had a scale marked in seconds.

---

As an aside, and a historical note, overflow in integer math control algorithms is particularly nasty since it tends to reverse the control action. Thus it must be avoided or detected and compensated for without fail. Fixed-point saturating math is well behaved, on the other hand, much like analog electronics.

Comment: I believe you're right about overflow: the AN964.zip's `pendulum.c`: `signed int derivative_term` is held to +/- 120 but then multiplied by `unsigned short kd` which is a 10-bit unsigned number from the ADC.  Microchip's compiler has [16-bit ints](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/%20GUID-BB433107-FD4E-4D28-BB58-9D4A58955B1A-en-US-1/index.html?GUID-3A37A613-2364-4965-9519-E79FE101ECC3).  120 * 1023 doesn't fit in 16-bits.  Also note there's some strange formatting of: `while (GODONE); { temp = 0; }` (eg line 244) while waiting for ADC to complete which `temp = 0` is not inside loop.

Comment: What about the last statement in the same section of the application? it says: "Kp·X·3·Ts precalculated to be 32 to increase the speed the PID loop"

Comment: I believe that's a reference to what I said about the markings on the Kp 'dial'.